# Where does Blob data reside?

Tags: javascript, html, blob, html5-filesystem

I may end up dealing with large amounts of data, represented by Blobs, in a long running web application. Some of them obtained using XHR (cache friendly), others created using `new Blob(...)`.

- Now if I've done my reading correctly, Blobs are backed either by disk or memory?
- How is this decided? (And do browsers follow the same rules?)
- Are there ways to force or guarantee certain behavior?

My concern is mostly how to manage these blobs. My initial idea was to just keep a references around. But it'd be bad if that kept large chunks of data in memory for the entire lifespan of the application.

Answer (score 4):

What I've discovered so far looking at Firefox source code: (**I have yet to get any of this verified!**)

Blob objects are instances of `nsDOMFile` subclasses. Implementation-wise, there's little distinction between a Blob and a File. They're either `nsDOMFileFile`, `nsDOMMemoryFile`, `nsDOMTemporaryFileBlob` or `nsDOMMultipartFile`.

Pretty much the only places `nsDOMMemoryFile` is used are:

- In `HTMLCanvasElement#toBlob`.
- In the Camera API.
- In the Media Recorder API.
- In WebSockets when when `binaryType` is `'blob'`.
- In WebRTC data channels when `binaryType` is `'blob'`.

All other places use `nsDOMFileFile` or `nsDOMTemporaryFileBlob`, and are thus backed by disk storage, with the exception of the `new Blob` constructor.

Blobs created using the `new Blob` constructor are instances of `nsDOMMultipartFile`. This class actually wraps a set of blobs (of the other three kinds described above), and represents them as one.

When passing a string or ArrayBuffer, they are copied into a new `nsDOMMemoryFile`, and then appended to the set. When passing an existing Blob of any kind, it is appended to the set as is. So an `nsDOMMultipartFile` may actually have mixed disk and memory storage backing.